# php + jquery + ajax fetch multiple value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working with jQuery AJAX. Using an AJAX call I invoke a PHP page. By default it returns a single value to the `success` function of AJAX. However I want to retrieve multiple data individually. What can I do?

Here's the jQuery code with AJAX , which returns a single value:

```
function getTime(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: {
      fd: sdate,
      sd: edate
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(msg) {
      $("#results").text(msg);
    }
  });
};
```

Test.php:

```php
echo $days;
echo $hours;
echo $minutes;
echo $seconds;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically to return multiple responses, the easiest way to do this is to return a json encoded array.  Something like the following should work.

```
echo json_encode( array(
    "days" => $days,
    "hours" => $hours,
    "minutes" => $minutes,
    "seconds" => $seconds
) );
```

Since your ajax request has `dataType: "text"` you will need to parse the response to use it with `JSON.parse(msg)`, however if you changed it to `dataType: "json"` you would not have to do this step as jQuery will try to auto parse it for you.

Comment: Hey OP, please accept Taplar's spot on answer if it worked and let us know :)

Answer (score 0):

your test.php would be like this

```
echo json_encode( array(
    "days" => $days,
    "hours" => $hours,
    "minutes" => $minutes,
    "seconds" => $seconds
));
```

and on ajax success

```
success: function(msg) {
    var result = $.parseJSON(msg);
    console.log(result.days)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to use array and encode it in JSON.

```
 echo json_encode( array(
  "days" => $days;
  "hours" => $hours;
  "minutes" => $minutes;
  "seconds" $seconds;
 )
);
```

but you should use the datatype **JSON** otherwise you have to parse the response like

```
    var result = $.parseJSON(response);
    console.log(result.days)
```